# how to set default selected for select 2 multiple choice

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

```
    echo $form->field($model, 'user_id[]', [
          ])->widget(Select2::classname(), [
          'data' => $user_data,
          'pluginOptions' => [
              'allowClear' => true,
              'placeholder' => 'Select user...',
              'multiple' => true,
          ],
      ])->dropDownList($user_data,     [
          'multiple'=>'multiple',
          'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',
         ]    )->label(Yii::t('app','User').' : ');
```

By using the code above, I am able to load data from the database and display to user on the list of users, where they can type and select a user. Let's say i want to set 2 default selected values such as user_id = 1 and 2, how can i do so in the select 2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an array of values to your select2 control and then refresh it.For example to select user_id 1 and 2 on page load, you will need to do the follwing.

```
var user_ids = [1,2];
$('#YourSelect2Control').val(user_ids);
$('#YourSelect2Control').select2();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by setting `Value` option of `widgets\Select2;` like

```
   echo $form->field($model, 'user_id[]', [
          ])->widget(Select2::classname(), [
          'data' => $user_data,
          'value' => [1, 2],  // Initial values, can also check with these value as string["1","2"],
           .
           .
```

Here is docs [Link](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-tags).

Hope this will work for u.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation from http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2:

```
// Tagging support Multiple
echo '<label class="control-label">Tag Multiple</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'color_1',
    'value' => ['red', 'green'], // initial value
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a color ...', 'multiple' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true,
        'maximumInputLength' => 10
    ],
]);
```

Note how the 'value' key has an array of values. This will set multiple default 'selected' options. The documentation does not show this functionality without usage of the 'tags' option however.